# How to Display months based on the Quarter Selection

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have 2 columns in Excel sheet, Column1 has the Quarter Selection dropdown box(Q1, Q2, Q3 and Q4). And Column2 has the month selction dropdown box.

I need help in the below.

Q1 - Feb, March, April

Q2 - May, Jun, July

Q3 - Aug, Sep, Oct

Q4 - Nov, Dec, Jan

Now if a user selects Quarter as Q2 in Column1, the Dropdown values in Column2 has to have only May, June and July.

I tried the grouping option but it doesn't help me.

Thanks in Advance,

Satish D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create two tables, one containing quarters, and other containing all quarters with corresponding months (tables are surrounded with thick border).

[image]

Then in cell `A2` create simple data validation and set list in `D1:D4` as source.
In cell `B1` also create data validation list, set `allow` to list, and in formula area please enter this formula `=OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH($A$1,E1:E12,0),5)),0,1,3,1)`

You data validation list in cell `B1` is now dependent on selection in list `A1`.